# how to import tailwind inside 'createGlobalStyle'

Tags: next.js, styled-components, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I'm trying to import tailwind inside my styled components globalstyle, to set base styles.

Code below doesn't work, so any suggestions on how to make it work?

```
import {createGlobalStyle} from 'styled-components';


const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  @tailwind base;
  @tailwind components;
  @tailwind utilities;
  
  @layer base {
    h1 {
      @apply text-2xl;
    }
    h2 {
      @apply text-xl;
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try twin.macro !!~~~

Click [here](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro)!

```
// src/styles/GlobalStyles.js
import React from 'react'
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'
import tw, { theme, GlobalStyles as BaseStyles } from 'twin.macro'

const CustomStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  body {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: ${theme`colors.purple.500`};
    ${tw`antialiased`}
  }
`

const GlobalStyles = () => (
  <>
    <BaseStyles />
    <CustomStyles />
  </>
)

export default GlobalStyles
```

Add the twin config

```
// babel-plugin-macros.config.js
module.exports = {
  twin: {
    preset: 'styled-components',
  },
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this library only works with projects that use Babel. As of today, SWC isn't supported.